# cdkDragFreeDragPosition position depends from each previous cdkDrag element

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-dragdrop

When i adding few cdkDrag elements on page, position each of them depends from previous element.
Looking on my screen, if i move "Item 3" to 0x0 of container, "Item 3" coordinates will -250x0.
So question is: how to make position of each element independent from previous elements? For example if i set x:0, y:0 for all elements, each one must be over another.

Of course i know one way, by calculating position depends from width and height of previous element, but maybe we have more elegant and easy way?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="example-boundary">
        <div cdkDrag class="design-box"
             [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="{x:0, y:0}"
             (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded_new($event)">
            Item 1
        </div>

        <div cdkDrag class="design-box"
             [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="{x:0, y:0}"
             (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded_new($event)">
            Item 2
        </div>

        <div cdkDrag class="design-box"
             [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="{x:0, y:0}"
             (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded_new($event)">
            Item 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can anybody help with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try putting your design-box class with

```
position: absolute
```

Comment: i was also facing this similar problem and I tried the solution from Kris Bishop and found out that I was already having my freeDragPosition set to 0,0 but your solution worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is old enough that you probably already got your answer, but if I understand the question correctly, the way you make the FreeDragPostion independent of other cdkDrag elements is by using different component references.  Something like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
   containers = [];
   ngOnInit() {
      this.containers[1]= {value:'Item 1', position: {x:0,y:0}};
      this.containers[2]= {value:'Item 2', position: {x:0,y:0}};
      this.containers[3]= {value:'Item 3', position: {x:0,y:0}};
   }
}
```

And your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="example-boundary">
        <div cdkDrag class="design-box" *ngFor="let c of containers"
             [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="c.position"
             (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded_new($event)">
            {{c.value}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```